# Oracle Apex and v$session_longops to monitor jobs

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex, dbms-scheduler

during my learning time in Oracle Apex now i need to send jobs to the dbms_scheduler in order to process some data. Looking on google i found this article https://apex.oracle.com/pls/apex/germancommunities/apexcommunity/tipp/2201/index-en.html

I've tried to implement the pkg_session_longops to use the view v$session_longops but after some trial and errors it seems that it doesn't show the corrent percentage of the job status. Looking at the view directly it seems that it create a new row in the v$session_longops for every update and the query return always the same row becouse they seems to be out of order. It's normal for the view to generate a new row for every update or should update the existing row? For me it seems not, otherwise i can't uderstand how i can order the rows to get the latest status update.

Comment: `v$session_longops` is ancient and has never been a useful tool. If your job is PL/SQL, you have to instrument your own status feedback if you wish to know where it is, unless you happen to know the # of executions of a particular looped SQL inside it, in which case you can watch the execution count in `v$sql`. If it's a single large SQL, then you'd need `v$sql_plan_monitor` to watch the # of rows emitted from the various plan lines and by reading the plan carefully you can estimate how much more it has to do.